# With JQ update JSON array with values from another one, namely JOIN

Tags: json, jq

Given two files `1.json` and `2.json`. They are both arrays of objects. Need to update field `ping_latency` to 1.json from 2.json

`1.json`

```json
[
    {
      "domain": "ca944.nordvpn.com",
      "name": "Canada #944",
      "ip_address": "172.83.40.219"
    },
    {
      "domain": "pl128.nordvpn.com",
      "name": "Poland #128",
      "ip_address": "194.99.105.100"
    },
    {
      "domain": "dk151.nordvpn.com",
      "name": "Denmark #151",
      "ip_address": "82.102.20.236"
    },
    {
      "domain": "be148.nordvpn.com",
      "name": "Belgium #148",
      "ip_address": "82.102.19.137",
      "ping_latency": 334
    }
]
```

`2.json`

```json
[
    {
      "domain": "ca944.nordvpn.com",
      "name": "Canada #944",
      "ip_address": "172.83.40.219",
      "ping_latency": 123
    },
    {
      "domain": "pl27.nordvpn.com",
      "name": "Poland #27",
      "ip_address": "194.99.105.27",
      "ping_latency": "REMOVED"
    },
    {
      "domain": "dk151.nordvpn.com",
      "name": "Denmark #151",
      "ip_address": "82.102.20.236",
      "ping_latency": 13
    },
    {
      "domain": "be148.nordvpn.com",
      "name": "Belgium #148",
      "ip_address": "82.102.19.137",
      "ping_latency": 67
    }
]
```

Object with mark "REMOVED" should not appear in result. Because it is not in 1.json.

PS <sub>I do not work for NordVPN - this is just an example.</sub>

---

I tried to merge arrays with operator `+` or `*`. But it always adds "REMOVED" domain.

```
jq -s 'map(INDEX(.domain)) | add | [.[]]' {1,2}.json
```

and

```
jq -s '(.[0]|INDEX(.domain)) as $x | (.[1]|INDEX(.domain)) as $y | $x *$y' {1,2}.json
```

Both adds "REMOVED" node from 2.json.

```json
[
  {
    "domain": "ca944.nordvpn.com",
    "name": "Canada #944",
    "ip_address": "172.83.40.219",
    "ping_latency": 123
  },
  {
    "domain": "pl128.nordvpn.com",
    "name": "Poland #128",
    "ip_address": "194.99.105.100"
  },
  {
    "domain": "dk151.nordvpn.com",
    "name": "Denmark #151",
    "ip_address": "82.102.20.236",
    "ping_latency": 13
  },
  {
    "domain": "be148.nordvpn.com",
    "name": "Belgium #148",
    "ip_address": "82.102.19.137",
    "ping_latency": 67
  },
  {
    "domain": "pl27.nordvpn.com",
    "name": "Poland #27",
    "ip_address": "194.99.105.27",
    "ping_latency": "REMOVED"
  }
]
```

How to manage it?

---

Update. After some mental fight I found a way and managed to do that in JQ

```
jq 'INDEX(.domain) as $u | 
     reduce ($full[][] | {domain,ip_address,name}) as $i (
     []; . + [ $i | .ping_latency=( $u[$i.domain].ping_latency//98767 )]
    )' --slurpfile full 1.json <2.json
```

But comparing to operator `*` my approach is about 100 times slower and takes up to 2 second on Intel Core i7-11xxx with array length of 5474 objects

```json
[
  {
    "domain": "ca944.nordvpn.com",
    "ip_address": "172.83.40.219",
    "name": "Canada #944",
    "ping_latency": 123
  },
  {
    "domain": "pl128.nordvpn.com",
    "ip_address": "194.99.105.100",
    "name": "Poland #128",
    "ping_latency": 98767
  },
  {
    "domain": "dk151.nordvpn.com",
    "ip_address": "82.102.20.236",
    "name": "Denmark #151",
    "ping_latency": 13
  },
  {
    "domain": "be148.nordvpn.com",
    "ip_address": "82.102.19.137",
    "name": "Belgium #148",
    "ping_latency": 67
  }
]
```

May be you know a quick better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `.domain` is unique to the updating objects in `2.json` (change if this holds true for another key instead; even spannig over multiple keys is possible using an array, e.g. `[.name, .ip_address]`), you could use `JOIN` based on the unique `INDEX` to match corresponding pairs of objects.

Furthermore, to combine a match, you could simply `add` up the pair's members, as nothing from `2.json` can effectively overwrite anything (else) in `1.json`, assuming your sample is representative to this regard. If this ish't the case, use a more fine-grained combination method instead, e.g. `first + (last | {ping_latency} | select(.[]) // {})` or similar.

Lastly, backed by your description

> Object with mark "REMOVED" should not appear in result. Because it is not in 1.json.

it is further assumed that there is generally no object in `2.json` which should **newly** be added to `1.json`. As `JOIN` behaves exactly that way, checking for `"REMOVED"` is believed to not be necessary.

Having the first file as input while reading the second file into a variable using `--argfile`:

```sh
jq --argfile a 2.json '[JOIN(INDEX($a[]; .domain); .[]; .domain; add)]' 1.json
```

Or, equivalently, reading in both files into one array using `--slurp`:

```sh
jq -s '[JOIN(INDEX(last[]; .domain); first[]; .domain; add)]' 1.json 2.json
```

```json
[
  {
    "domain": "ca944.nordvpn.com",
    "name": "Canada #944",
    "ip_address": "172.83.40.219",
    "ping_latency": 123
  },
  {
    "domain": "pl128.nordvpn.com",
    "name": "Poland #128",
    "ip_address": "194.99.105.100"
  },
  {
    "domain": "dk151.nordvpn.com",
    "name": "Denmark #151",
    "ip_address": "82.102.20.236",
    "ping_latency": 13
  },
  {
    "domain": "be148.nordvpn.com",
    "name": "Belgium #148",
    "ip_address": "82.102.19.137",
    "ping_latency": 67
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/WUNqbQFC_q)

Comment: Thank you. This is much more laconic. Performance at first glance is similar.